# GVimを用いた印刷について

Tags: vim

Gvimに印刷コマンドがありますが他のエディタにある機能が使えないです。
ググりましたがうまくでてきません。

1. 2段組にできないです。
2. ヘッダは`set printheader=%<%f%h%m%=Page\ %N`などでいけますがフッタをつけられないです。
3. `set printoptions=number:y`で行番号を表示させることはできましたが黒で潰れてしまいます。カラー印刷でも同様ですがかろうじて見えるようになります。
   ちなみにカラーをmolokaiにしていますがその影響でしょうか。。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。